# React.js Sub-Menu dimensions only available after ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following:

A simple top menu with a drop down sub menu system:

```
<div id="menuBar">
   <div id="menuItemA">
      <div ref="refMenuItemA-DropList"
           onMouseOut={ this.hideSubMenu.bind(this, this.props.item) }
           onMouseOver={ this.showSubMenu.bind(this, this.props.item) } 
             style={ { 
                     display: this.state.display, 
                     opacity: this.state.opacity, 
                     left: this.state.left, 
                     top: this.state.top, 
                     width: this.state.width 
                     } }> 
         <div id="subMenuItemA" ref="refSubMenuItem"> SubMenuItem A 
                <div id="subSubMenuItemA">subSubMenuItemA</div>
                      .......
                      .......
         </div>
         <div id="subMenuItemB"> SubMenuItem B </div>
         <div id="subMenuItemC"> SubMenuItem C </div>
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

At initial render:

```
this.state = {
  opacity: 0,
  display: 'none',
  bottom: 0,
  height: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 0,
  selected: ''
};
```

When the `onMouseOver` event fires, I can easily determine what the `this.state.top & this.state.left` will be for `refMenuItemA-DropList`, because, its parent `MenuItemA` was always visible ...

1. I can retrieve the ref values of `refMenuItemA-DropList`, find it's parent's left & bottom properties and pass them along to state; and,
2. Change the < div> owning `refMenuItemA-DropList` to visible and with a properly positioned left and top given in #1 above.
3. But I will not be able to determine that same div's width as it's state has not changed to visible yet.

Moreover, trying to retrieve the top of the <div> owning `refSubMenuItem`, and the width value mentioned in #3, and pass them to its children will be futile in that same `mouse-over` event because state values will not update until `componentDidUpdate`, thus opacity is still 0 and display is still 'none'.

Question:

If state does not get updated until `componentDidUpdate`, and I cannot set state in `componentDidUpdate`, how can I pass values along to a sub menu item's children so they can align properly, once state does update to make the element visible, as an element being visible is required to retrieve size/position values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really thought long and hard about this. While the docs at ReactJS strongly advise against messing with state in `componentDidUpdate`, the more I researched, the more people were just pointing out there was no other way.

I received no errors, no warnings, there was no slowness in the app and I have over 100 routes, and like an old mule I beat the app time and time again to find any degradation, and there was none.

So as not to confuse you with above, in my app, the actual ref name was not
`refMenuItemA-DropList1 but rather 1refFlyList`

So this is my solution ...

I. top-nav-menu-item.js

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const self = this;
    if (self.refs.refFlyList !== undefined) {
      const refFlyList = self.refs.refFlyList.clientWidth;

      // need this or endless loop
      if (refFlyList === this.state.width) return;

      if (refFlyList !== 0) {
        this.setState( { width: refFlyList } );
      }
    }   
  }

 fetchSubMenu(node) {
    if (node.childNodes !== undefined) {
      const parentDims= {
        width: this.state.width,
        top: this.state.top,
        left: this.state.left
      };
      return (
        node.childNodes.map((childNode, index) => {
          return (
            <SubMenuItem key={ index }
                         node={ childNode }
                         parentDims={ parentDims }
            />
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

II. sub-menu-item.js

```
  showSubMenu(node, event) {
    if (node.childNodes !== undefined) {
      const parentDims = this.props.parentDims;
      if (this.state.top === 0) {
        this.setState({
          left: parentDims.width,
          top: event.clientY - parentDims.top
        });
      }
      this.setState({
        opacity: 1,
        display: 'block',
        selected: ' selected'
      });
    }
  }
```

III. If like me you are using a linting helper (I use EsLint):

```
  "rules": {
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 0,
     .....................
```

My react-router is dynamic [data comes from Mongo] and it is recursive. While I only go as far as 3 levels, I played around with 6 levels and everything still worked fine.

The solution doesn't feel like a hack and performance is great!